# Allow horizontal scrolling on table with bottom visible at all times

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I'd like to add a horizontal scroll to a bootstrap page. Currently the way it is set up is to have the user scroll all the way to the bottom of the page the page and then use the horizontal scroll. I'd like to have it set up so the scroll is always visible. I have recreated the issue in jsfiddle.

### [Js-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/886xfe6d/17)

```
<table class="table">
```

Comment: How you approach this depends entirely on what's in the page above the table. You'll need to either 1) use flex-box to set an appropriate height on the table, or 2) establish a fixed height for the header/content above the table and use top padding to allow space for it above the table. Please update the fiddle to show the full page.

Comment: @isherwood You are using table-responsive that's why the scroll is moving to the bottom of the page just remove the responsive from all thought your design will change little bit but you can set it with css https://jsfiddle.net/Siddharth_Pandey/5usukas1/

Answer (score 2):

If you still want it to be like this but this is not hte proper thing to do in bootstrap add the following css property

```
.container{
    overflow:scroll;
    position:absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Siddharth_Pandey/5usukas1/

Answer (score 0):

You are using table-responsive that's why the scroll is moving to the bottom of the page just remove the responsive from all thought your design will change little bit but you can set it with css jsfiddle.net/Siddharth_Pandey/5usukas1

Comment: I like the responsive design on the tables. I am looking for a scroll bar on top of the responsive design

Comment: actually when you keep you table inside the div and the and your table content flow outside the div so it will show the scroll bar in the end of the div and when you use normal table bootstrap the page will be considered as the outer element if the content flow outside of it it shows at the bottom of the visible part of page