# Keep responsive table horizontal scroll bar above my footer

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a responsive table that is between a fixed navbar to the top of the screen, and another fixed to the bottom of it (that's my footer)

You can see it [here](http://codepen.io/Pancreatico/pen/bgWagZ) (by visualization I have not made a fiddle).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Hi</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap Tema opcional -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #tablecontainer{
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    #footer{
        margin-top: 120px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavbarBrand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="afile.html">Simple link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- fin navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- fin container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" id="tablecontainer">
  <center>
    <div class="table table-responsive">
        <section>
          <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>thisisaveryverylongword</th>
                      <th>thisisaveryverylongword</th>
                      <th>thisisaveryverylongword</th>
                      <th>thisisaveryverylongword</th>
                      <th>thisisaveryverylongword</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                        <td>thisisaveryverylongword</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
        </section>
    </div>
    <br><br>
  </center>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inner  navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse mifooter">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <p style="color:white">somecontent</p>
          <p style="color:white">somecontent</p>
          <p style="color:white">somecontent</p>
          <p style="color:white">somecontent</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <p style="color:white">somecontent</p>
          <p style="color:white">somecontent</p>
          <p style="color:white">somecontent</p>
          <p style="color:white">somecontent</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you dim the screen width (at 900px for example) and then you go to the bottom of the table, you can see the horizontal scroll bar at the end of the table.

I need that horizontal scroll bar always be visible, for that it would be optimal to always **visualize it above my footer**, regardless of whether I am at the beginning, middle or at the end of the table.

I've tried what they say in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009880/allow-horizontal-scrolling-on-table-with-bottom-visible-at-all-times) post, but it does not work for me because of the structure of my page.

I'll appreciate any help.

**EDIT**: I need to keep my footer just like it is right now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1/ maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to maintain the styling, you need to get rid of the `fixed` positioning on footer.

```
#footer .navbar{ position: static; }
```

Get rid of margin on `#footer`:

```
    #footer{ margin-top: 120px; }
```

And delete the two random `br` tags, along with `center`:

```
<br><br></center>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdvQeO

Comment: but I need that footer always visible just like it is right now.